# Unable to get checkbox value from display tag to in my action class?

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am using checkbox in display tag, but I want to pass one of the column data as a checkbox value, but I am unable to retrieve the checkbox value, it is returning `null`.

This is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="allbox" onclick="checkAll(this.form)"/>

<form name="editForm" action="WorkListResults.jsp">
    <input type="submit" name="method" value="Delete" class="button" />
    <br /><br />

    <display:table name="test" uid="test" class="list">
        <display:column style="width: 5%" title="${checkAll}"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="id" style="margin: 0 0 0 4px" onclick="checkbox(this)" value="${id.rowNum}" />
            <c:if test="${param.WORKITEMID == test.WORKITEMID and param.method != 'Save'}" checked="checked"</c:if>
        </display:column>
        <display:column title="First Name">
        </display:column>
        <html:hidden property="WORKITEMID" value='<%=request.getParameter("WORKITEMID")%>'/>
        <display:column class="WORKITEMID" property="WORKITEMID"  paramId="WORKITEMID" paramProperty="WORKITEMID"
            title="WORKITEMID" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" maxLength="50" />     
    </display:table>
</form>
```

Comment: first where your checkbox here?

Comment: Please check the above code

Comment: show us whatever you have done first, it will help you to get exact and quick answer. :)

Comment: Satya and Vishal : please check the above code

Comment: write codes in comments is not the right way, go to other questions see how to ask right questions.

Comment: are you using `ajax call` or `form submit`.

Comment: check the html generated code.

Comment: @Ashwani Sharma, check the html generated code to see whether a checkbox `sid` contains a value or not. post server side code also. its not enough to resolve.

Comment: Satya: Let me know whta other information u need

Comment: @Ashwani Sharma, complete form with server side code. provide only the logic. I think as a programmer we know that which part have to post to understand it clearly the problem.